# How do I use cut to output initial line in different format?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cut

I have a file like this:

```
A: 1.2.3.4       Z: xxx             R: a              Q W
A: 5.6.7.8       Z: yyy             R: b              X Y
A: 9.10.11.12    Z: zzz             R: c              L N X
```

The desired output after running command like `cut` or `sed` *(something which exists in 99% of Linux environments)*:

```
1.2.3.4:xxx:a:Q-W
5.6.7.8:yyy:b:X-Y
9.10.11.12:zzz:c:L-N-X
```

Comment: Share your command please.

Comment: What is the pattern between columns? Tab? Also, what is the algorithm in this? For the 3 first, print after `:` and for the last column the whole value?

Comment: @soundhax If you have a comment on a question then use the "add comment" link, don't edit destructively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s:%s:%s:",$2,$4,$6;for(i=7;i<NF;i++)printf "%s-",$i;print $NF}' file 
1.2.3.4:xxx:a:Q-W
5.6.7.8:yyy:b:X-Y
9.10.11.12:zzz:c:L-N-X
```

**Explanation**:

The script will run for every line in the file:

```
printf "%s:%s:%s:",$2,$4,$6;    # print the 2nd, 4th, 6th field separated by a :
for(i=7;i<NF;i++)               # from the 7th field to the penultimate field
printf "%s-",$i;                # print the field value followed by a -
print $NF                       # print the last field (followed by a newline)
```

Answer (score 0):

Through sed,

```
$ sed 's/^[^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\([^[:space:]]\+\)[[:space:]]\+[^:]*:[[:space:]]\+\([^[:space:]]\+\)[[:space:]]\+[^:]*:[[:space:]]\+\([^[:space:]]\+\)[[:space:]]\+/\1:\2:\3:/;s/[[:space:]]\+/-/g' file
1.2.3.4:xxx:a:Q-W
5.6.7.8:yyy:b:X-Y
9.10.11.12:zzz:c:L-N-X
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version of awk would be like

```
$ awk -F[\ :]+ '{print $2":"$4":"$6":"$7"-"$8}' input
1.2.3.4:xxx:a:Q-W
5.6.7.8:yyy:b:X-Y
9.10.11.12:zzz:c:L-N
```

- `-F[\ :]+` sets the field seperator as space or `:`

Comment: It looks like the number of fields per record isn't the same, this misses the `X` of the last record for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/  *[A-Z]: */:/g;s/...//;s/\(:[a-z]\)  */\1:/;s/  */-/g' YourFile
```

without more spec on `xxx`, `yyy`, ...